# DRY Principle with DTO and EO for spring and hibernate enabled webapp

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-applications, dry

I have a web application which is spring and hibernate enabled

I have a class for user registration :

```
public class SignUpDto {

@NotBlank
@Length(min = 1, max = 50)
private String firstName;

@NotBlank
@Length(min = 1, max = 50)
private String lastName;

@NotBlank
@Length(min = 1, max = 100)
@Email
private String email;

@NotBlank
@Length(min = 8, max = 15)
private String password;

@NotBlank
@Length(min = 8, max = 15)
private String confirmPassword;

@NotBlank
@Length(min = 10, max = 12)
@Phone
private String phone;

@NotNull
private UserType userType;
....
```

and corresponding hibernate entity Object which is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEo extends BaseEo {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UserEo() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "use_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "use_title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "use_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "use_email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "use_password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "use_type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "use_registered")
    private Timestamp registered;

    @Column(name = "use_phone")
    private String phone;
...
```

so my concern is about code fields /setters/getters are being repeated in DTO and EO which violates DRY principle

Any suggestions how to overcome this issue ?

Thanks
Suresh

Answer (score 4):

This is a common issue when using the DTO pattern, the short answer is there is not much (anything?) you can do to overcome this in your particular situation.  Now for the longer answer:

The DTO pattern does two things- one it decouples your API (e.g. REST/SOAP API) from your implementation.  Second it allows you to transfer only the information  needed by the consumer, regardless of your implementation. The domain model can also be manipulated as part of constructing the DTO.

Your implementation as is has both these advantages, you can more easily maintain your API interface even if the underlying implementation (your database table) changes.

A naive approach is to use the entity object as the DTO as well.  This usually does not work since it violates the principles above.  It is also technically difficult if the entity takes advantage of lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to reuse user object (UserEo) instead of creating DTO? You can use JSR303 (Bean Validation) annotations on entity class without problems.

Another way is to use reflection or tools like Apache BeanUtils 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#package_description

to automatically copy values from entity to DTO.

Comment: Because exposing entity objects through services is bad practice. Have a separate DTO and Entity. Have services return DTO-s. Do not couple your entity to a client.

Comment: There are not so many fields which must be excluded from output due to security reasons and it's very easy to do so, for example by adding annotations like '@XmlTransient' or '@JsonIgnore'. I think this is better way for common applications than support a lot of duplicated code with DTO.

Comment: You can get away with this in a tiny project or do it for a practice purpose. If start putting validation logic in your entity object along with all the JPA annotations and what not then this class will end up looking so ugly that you don't understand what's going on in there.